# Is it possible to set a UIImageView as the background of a prototype UITableViewCell in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, interface-builder

If I set a `UIImageView` as the `backgroundView` of a **prototype cell** of a `UITableView` in Interface Builder, then create a table with more than one row using the prototype, then only the last created cell gets its `backgroundView` set to the `UIImageView` instance.

I am assuming the reason for this is that when I connect the `backgroundView` outlet of my prototype cell in Interface Builder to the UIImageView, I am essentially connecting it to a **single instance** of a `UIImageView`. So as new cells get created, each new cell has its `backgroundView` set to the `UIImageView` instance, stealing it from the previously created cell.

Is there any way to configure Interface Builder such that each new cell created from the prototype gets its `backgroundView` set correctly? It seems odd that IB let's you connect a prototype cell's `backgroundView` outlet to a `UIImageView` if only one cell can ever use the view.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to subclass UITableViewCell.  Make your prototype cell an instance of your custom cell, and connect the imageView in the prototype to an outlet in the customCell class.  For each cell in your tableView, instantiate an instance of your customCell, and set its imageView.